Should I use the speaker's native language for single word exclamations?
I'm writing in English and most of the dialogue is translated to English. But the character in question is actually speaking Dutch. In the instance when they touch something hot and jerk their hand away, should they say "crap!" or "Kak!" followed by a translation?

This looks like it might be answered by Leaving non-English dialogue untranslated?

If the curses (in-story) are in the same language as other dialogue for which translation convention is in place, I strongly recommend keeping the translation convention for the curses as well.
If you leave only the curses untranslated, you'll make it sound as if the character is cursing in a different language than they otherwise speak. You'd be giving your reader an impression of your character as a foreigner who speaks a second language for the sake of their conversation partner, but slips into their first when inadvertently cursing, or something like that.
I wonder if you're uncomfortable writing out curses in your story, and putting them in Dutch is a way for you to "soften" them. Don't do this (it doesn't work anyway). If your story calls for a hero who swears freely, show them swearing freely. Don't be shy and apologetic about it. As a reader I don't appreciate an author who doesn't stand by their story and their words.
Peppering a story set in a foreign country with that place's words that have a perfectly good equivalent in the language of the text is a very lazy way to paint the setting. Give proper descriptions instead. Capture the everyday customs of the people. Use a Dutch word only where English doesn't have a good one for you.

Exactly this! Expletives and other little things in French is what reminds the reader that Hercule Poirot is a Belgian living in the UK and speaking a foreign language. Using the same technique if he were to travel home to Belgium would do nothing but suggest that he was speaking English to his Belgian friends for no good reason.

By interspersing the English dialogue with some Dutch words and phrased you can unobtrusively remind your readers that your characters are actually speaking Dutch and add some exotic coloring (for non-Dutch readers) to your narrative.
It is best to give only those words and phrases in Dutch whose meaning will be apparent to your readers from the context and doesn't need to be explained or translated. In your example, it is clear that Kak! is an exclamation that people say when they burn their hands; something that expresses surprise and pain and irritation.
It isn't clear if it is a mild exclamation like Dang! or vulgar like Fuck!, but maybe that isn't so very imporant to the story, and if it is you can have another character react in a way that explains what kind of expletive it was.
Explanations, if you feel they are necessary, don't have to be given immediately but can come a few pages later.

In my opinion, foreign words in English narration only make sense if there is a viewpoint character who isn't a native speaker of the foreign language but who understands it (e.g. a Dutch-speaking American living or travelling in the Netherlands). If your novel takes place in a location that is foreign only to your readers but every character in your story is a native speaker of that foreign language, translate everything into English.

Like Ben I agree that interspersing English with some Dutch words is a good idea to add some Dutch flavour to your book.
However I think the specific example is not very well chosen. As a native Dutch speaker I can assure you nobody uses "Kak" as a curseword, "shit" is used in these instances.
To give you some suggestions for good Dutch single word curse exclamations: "kut", "kanker", "typhus", "godver", "godverdegodver".

It's worth noting that some people might find some of your examples offensive. Especially "kanker" and "godver" (and variations on it) are controversial. Many people still use them of course, but it's something to keep in mind when thinking about using them in your writing.

@thieupepijn Good examples, I would add the classic 'godverdomme!' to the list too. In the case of actually burning your hand rather than nearly "Au! Gódverdomme!" is really in order. For the OP's question 'kut!' is probably the most realistic (or even 'kutzooi' for dismay at the whole situation). 'Fuck!' would be totally on-point too, but of course lacks the inherent 'Dutchness' sought. Some people do use 'kak', but it always feels weird and 'undutch' to me.

Please excuse the downvote, but this doesn't seem to be an answer to OP's question at all. OP didn't ask for help choosing the correct swearword. Also, this answer is helpful only in that one specific instance in OP's work. I doesn't help OP choose other good words in other parts of their writing. And it doesn't help anyone who is interested in answers to OP's question but doesn't use Dutch as a foreign language. Therefore -1.

@Ben What this answer is saying (implicitly) is that, if you're going to use words in a foreign language, make sure you know that language well, or consult with someone who does. Don't ask Google to translate your words for you, it can end up looking very weird.

Often when people learn a second languages, things like expletives, swears, and curses are the first thing they learn. Often for banal and humorous reasons. However it's often observed that when expletives are used, it's often an involuntary or reflexive reaction as per your example. In these cases, people tend to swear in their original language most of the time. So if your character was speaking in English, for example, and reacted to something with an expletive in Dutch, it would make perfect sense.
Expletives and similar words are perfect to leave untranslated as well, as it isn't the meaning of the word that brings the impact of it, it's the vulgarity. If it's clear that it's an expletive, the meaning doesn't matter as much, just the fact that the character swore conveys the intent of the dialogue. The only reason things like these would have to be translated, is if a character has a reaction to the meaning of the swear word, not just the fact that it was used.
However, it doesn't make sense if the entire dialogue is in Dutch, and only the swears aren't translated. This would suggest the dialogue is taking place in two distinct languages, whereas from your question it seems to be just the one. This should be avoided to prevent confusion to the reader if any of the characters ever do speak the language the book is translated to.
If your goal is to convey the fact the story is set in The Netherlands, or is about a Dutch person, there are other ways to do this. Especially highlighting cultural and societal norms seems effective, like the Dutch directness, love of coffee, or doing things that are "gezellig".
Other ways could be to (sparingly) use Dunglish, by literally translating some Dutch sayings and colloquialisms instead of finding English equivalents. For example "fluitje van een cent" becomes "that's a penny whistle" instead of "piece of cake". However, this is to be done sparingly as not to confuse your readers too much, and if the meaning of these sayings isn't obvious from context this should be provided as well.
